# Run terraform plan/init on AWS instance without internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I`m trying to run terraform within AWS instance without internet connection.

I have already managed to configure terraform to run with offline modules (terraform init)

for now Im trying minimal action as deploy another AWS instance

credentials are configured, and Im using verbose mode

```
Action=GetUser&Version=2010-05-08
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Send Request iam/GetUser failed, attempt 0/1, error RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://iam.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 52.119.198.223:443: i/o timeout
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Retrying Request iam/GetUser, attempt 1
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request iam/GetUser Details:
Host: iam.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.35.19 (go1.14.5; linux; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.2.7 (+https://www.terraform.io)
Content-Length: 33
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<MY KEY>/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=2af8836c385a80f3d49d88ac
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20220823T142231Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

which is understood... but how do I bypass it?
thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to deploy something in a cloud provider which is using terraform code which requires internet access to be able to hit AWS API endpoints, but without internet access?

Comment: iirc you can create VPC Endpoints to required AWS Service, if its IAM then VPC endpoints for IAM in your used region. but not sure VPC Endpoints have IAM service support.

Comment: seem IAM endpoint not supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html

Comment: @MarkoE - exactly!

Comment: And how do you think that could work?

Comment: endpoints maybe.. not sure yet

Comment: @MarkoE checkout out my answer

Answer (score 1):

well, I have managed to do so.
hope it will help someone else in the future.

used env variable to skip terraform checks

```
export CHECKPOINT_DISABLE=true
```

configured my provider like so:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  endpoints {
   ec2 = "vpce-XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com"
}
```

also managed to deploy various other AWS services this way (: